# Jest unit test fails for a property when it is not tagged by @api

Tags: salesforcedx, lwc-jest

That is a chunk of the JS code

```js
export default class CurrencyUI extends LightningElement {

@api dropdownValue = 'USD';
```

That is the code for Jest

```js
it('Currency default value', () => {
    const element = createElement('currency-ui-test', {
        is: CurrencyUI
    });

    console.log('Currency default value Unit Test: ' + element.dropdownValue);
    expect(element.dropdownValue).toEqual('USD');
});
```

I don't understand why I have to tag the dropdown property with @api to run the test successfully. If someone of you could explain me what I don't understand ?

Many thanks,
Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jest is intended for [black-box testing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black-box_testing), which means you're not meant to test for the internals of your component -- you test for its effects.  The philosophy is that it doesn't matter what the value of `dropdownValue` is.  What matters is how your component renders, and how it responds to user actions, events from other components, etc.  A response may be to update the DOM, to dispatch an event, to set a new value on a child component, etc.

Based on the name you've given `dropdownValue`, I'll bet you can query for an element in the DOM that contains its value (a `lightning-combobox`, possibly?).  Then you can assert about the value of that element, e.g.:

```js
it('Currency default value', () => {
    const element = createElement('currency-ui-test', {
        is: CurrencyUI
    });

    // Look for a lightning-combobox
    const dropdown = element.shadowRoot.querySelector('lightning-combobox');
    // Check that the lightning-combobox is in the DOM
    expect(dropdown).toBeTruthy();
    // Check the value property of the lightning-combobox
    expect(dropdown.value).toEqual('USD');
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that's more clear

Answer (score 2):

This is because the property is not accessible by JEST unless it is exposed with the @api annotation or is somehow rendered. This leaves you with the option to either expose it through @api or to add it to the markup in some fashion, such as in a data attribute on an element. In the latter case you can go diving with querySelector to get to it.

Everything else is effectively under the hood and not exposed.

Comment: Thanks Matthew. Honestly I'm quite lost because I believed all the class members were public in JS